# jQuery: show() function issue

Tags: jquery

On my page, I generate a  click() in jquery. It will show a div in the middle. I set z-index to 999. But, under this div, there are also some links. When I hover the div, these links will also be selected. How can I force stop these links when I show the div. I want to top this div and ignore all the other elements until I close this div. How can I do that?

Comment: show us html and css you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you showed us your code, in any case you could use an overlay `<div>` with a Z-index of 998 and wich is as big as the screen, exactly what a [modal diolg does in jQuery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

```
//this is the "background" in the jquert ui link
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 1350px; height: 1258px; z-index: 1002;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead `z-index`, use `position:absolute;`